# required and some validation not supported by safari browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, safari

I use validation like required in javascript and some validation done using script. That well worked in chrome and firefox but not in safari. waht type of script supported by safari. is that any site to refer it. And my one of validation like this,

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("amount");
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].oninvalid = function (e) {
            e.target.setCustomValidity("");
            if (!e.target.validity.valid) {
                e.target.setCustomValidity("Amount Must be Valid and Cannot be Greater than the Balance Amount !");
            }
        };
        elements[i].oninput = function (e) {
            e.target.setCustomValidity("");
        };
    }
})
```

Is there any other possible to validate this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `but not in safari` - do you get errors in the console? more details you give the better chance of getting any help at all

Comment: There is not a console error.

Comment: is `setCustomValidity` coming from a library? or is it supposed to be a native element method?

Comment: @JaromandaX validation message not displayed in safari browser. but in other browser it displayed.

Comment: what version of safari?

Comment: safari version 10.0.2.